# i have problem with material ui select in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using material UI select with next js
and on the page, I have some errors i can't fix that
[image]

this section code

```
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

<Select defaultValue="1"  variant="standard" value={sampleref.current} ref={sampleref} onChange={handleChange}>
            <MenuItem value="1" className="1" >1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="2" className="2">2</MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

Comment: That's just a warning from React's StrictMode about a deprecated API (`findDOMNode`) being used in Material UI. What version of `@material-ui` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Strict mode in `next.config.js` :

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false, // React Strict Mode is off
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```